# gnuplot and awk syntax problems

Tags: awk, gnuplot

I've managed to get a graph automatically plotted from live data on my system, using a gpuplot script, piping the raw data through awk. The script command.gpl is below:

```
#------------------------run this file--------------------
#gnuplot /usr/src/scripts/plots/core_temp_data/command.gpl
#---------------------------------------------------------


set terminal png size 2100,1000
set output '/usr/src/scripts/plots/core_temp_data/output_sat.png'

set title "Core Temp versus Time"
set size ratio 0.4
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M"

plot "<awk '/Mon/{print $4, substr($0,match($0,/temp=[0-9.]+/)+5,RLENGTH-5)}' /var/log/rebootlogfile.log" using 1:2 with points # works
```

I would like to be able to:

1. Add variables to make the plot line more readable

   eg.

   **condition**=`"/Mon/"` and **action**=`"print $4,substr($0,match($0,/temp=[0-9.]+/)+5,RLENGTH-5)"`
2. Apply if then conditions to it

   eg

   if the record starts with Mon
     then plot "plot code for Mon"

   or if the record starts with Tue 
     then plot "plot code for Tue"

However, each time I try and separate the plot line I get syntax errors.

Can I do these things, if so how?

This is a link to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019396/adding-conditions-to-a-gnuplot-awk-script/26032436#26032436) with how I got to this stage.

Comment: Huh? You already have the condition that `Mon` is in the line inside your `awk`. If you want `Tue`, just change `/Mon/` to `/Tue/`.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear, I want to be able to perform `if then else`, **on other stuff too**, within the plot line. However I'm struggling to order it like I would a traditional multi-line script as appose to it all being on the same line **plot "blar blar blar"**

Comment: Oh, that's easy. Put all the `awk` script in a separate file called `script.awk` - make it as complicated as you like with `if` statements etc - then use `awk -f script.awk`

Comment: This is a great intro to `awk` http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your question is a bit too broad and I think you should decide on a specific problem you would like to solve. It sounds like you might benefit from using `sprintf` in gnuplot to build your command string. For example:

```
condition = "/Mon/"
action = "print $4,substr($0,match($0,/temp=[0-9.]+/)+5,RLENGTH-5)"    
file = "/path/to/file"
cmd = sprintf("<awk '%s {%s}' %s", condition, action, file)

plot cmd with points
```